# ¿Como mostrar campos especificos en un JComboBox desde una tabla que cuenta con varios campos?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jframe, combobox

Mi pregunta es como puedo evitar ésto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y obtener este resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que deseo es listar solamente el campo nombre y apellido de los clientes dentro del combo, por el momento me lista el nombre y los apellidos pero me muestra los demas campos en **null** que posee mi tabla de la bbdd lo cual no quiero que se muestren.

Para cargar el combobox hago lo siguiente:

```
public DefaultComboBoxModel cargarClientes() {
        this.iniciarTransacciones();
        this.query = this.session.createQuery("FROM Clientes");
        List<Clientes> listaClientes = this.query.list();
        this.transaction.commit();
        DefaultComboBoxModel<Clientes> defaultComboBoxModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>();
        for (Clientes listaCliente : listaClientes) {
            //En esta parte hago trabajar el modelo con mi clase Clientes, obtengo el idCliente y el NombreApellido.
            defaultComboBoxModel.addElement(new Clientes(listaCliente.getClientesidCliente(), listaCliente.getNombreApellido()));
        }
        return defaultComboBoxModel;
    }
```

En el JFrame donde se encuentra el JComboBox hago:

```
private void cargarClientes() {
        try {
            DefaultComboBoxModel modeloCliente = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
            modeloCliente = transaccionesControlIngresosDiario.cargarClientes();
            JcboClientes.setModel(modeloCliente);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se ha producido una excepción al cargar los clientes en la lista deplegable.\n" + e, "Excepción", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
```

Estoy utilizando **hibernate 4.3.1** desde ya gracias por su ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: Lo más fácil es crear un query en el que solo pidas los campos especificos, por ejemplo: ("SELECT ES.nombre FROM ESTUDIANTE ES")

Comment: Claro, lo entiendo tu respuesta pero cuando intento hacer lo que sugieres me lanza una excepcion del tipo **java.lang.String cannot be cast to Modelo.Clientes** es decir, si se ejecuta una consulta HQL con un solo campo en el SELECT, la lista devuelta contendrá objetos del tipo de ese campo. Es decir, está obteniendo una lista de objetos **String** en este caso en particular.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando te traes la consulta de la base de datos el separador puede ser una coma(,) o un espacio en blanco( ), asi que puedes usar un split para separar la informacion y extraer la data de interes.

```
consulta.split(" ").[0] // extraer el primer valor solamente.
```

Otra manera seria que en tu SELECT colocaras solo la columna que te interesa extraer para que solo recuperar ese tipo de dato

```
SELECT nombres, apellidos FROM tabla;
```